# Japan's Maglev Train propulsion and guidance system

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, resistors

[image]

Above image is taken from Japan's Maglev Train youtube video by Lesics at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjwF-STGtfE&t=585s).

If the electromagnets along the two walls used for guidance of the train (So that it does not hit the walls)  is made up of iron core, **wouldnt** the train which is represented by the bar magnet **(in this case the train leans to the right as shown in image)** be attracted to the iron core attached to the walls and cause an imbalance which means it will hit the walls? Or is it that the propulsion and the guidance electromagnets are made up of pure copper coil (non-magnetic) without the iron core so that the train does not stick on the side of the walls? It's pretty counter-intuitive if you were to think about it.

Comment: the electromagnets are *not* made of iron core – their cores might be, but what is shown in your picture is not the core, but the windings.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, hi, but in reality, do they use iron core for the electromagnets along the tracks to amplify the propulsion force?

Comment: When the train is at stop or low speed, i believe that it will somehow stick to the sides of the walls or track if  propulsion coils contain iron core inside of them?

Comment: the whole point of the stabilization system is that it actively counteracts the train going off the rail sideways, that's why it's there.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, well, what if the train is at low speed, the superconducting magnets of the train will stick to the sides of the tracks right if the tracks were to be made up of copper coils with iron cores inside them :) ?

Comment: If the train is stationary, imagine what would happen, it would stick to the sides of the track :)

Comment: why are you assuming you turn of the control system when the train is at rest?

Comment: also asked at https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56417/japans-maglev-train-propulsion-and-guidance-system

Comment: Only the propulsion coil is powered and not the guidance coil, the guidance coils are the one that does the levitation and stabilization magic. Thus, if the speed of train is low, it might not have enough correcting force to balance the train horizontally that prevents hitting the sides of walls. That is why i put the assumption when the train speed is low, or stationary, the control system is referring to the propulsion coils to be exact if you have understood the video ? Cheers:)

Comment: yes, but what you assume – the stabilization coils being to weak to keep the train centered – would mean the system wouldn't work in motion. So, that assumption seems wrong.

Comment: At a determined speed wheels are lowered because levitation and guidance do not work at lower speeds, as shown in the video.